# Positioning list and pictures on Beamer frame

Tags: beamer, positioning, columns

I have the following code to generate a frame with itemisation on the left and two images on the right:

```
\begin{frame}{Acknowledgments}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}       
        Text... 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item{a}
                \item{b}
                \item{c}
                \item{d} \linebreak
            \end{itemize}
        Text...
            \begin{itemize}
                \item{d}
                \item{e}
                \item{f}
                \item{g}
                \item{h}
                \item{i}
            \end{itemize}
         \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.2, keepaspectratio]{something.pdf} \linebreak
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.3, keepaspectratio]{something2.jpg}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

There are two problems with this:

1. The itemisation is too long and reaches beyond the frame through the bottom. How can I decrease the font size for this column only to make it fit on one page?
2. The two images appear between the two itemisations on the right, but I would like them at the top right of the frame. How can I specify this?

I am new to Beamer, but haven't found these questions before. I have searched and found the column environment, which I used as above, but these two issues I couldn't solve. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please complete your code to Minimal Working Example (MWE), small document which we can copy to our computers and compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I complete your code snppet to MWE ... see, if the following is what you after for:

[image]

For picture i use`example-image` from `graphicx` package (loaded by `beamer`) and set its size to second column width. For aligning both columns on the top *beamer* provide align option `T`. For smaller font size use desired size in the first column (see code below):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Acknowledgments}
\begin{columns}[T]% <-- added
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}\scriptsize% <-- added
        Text...
            \begin{itemize}
                \item{a}
                \item{b}
                \item{c}
                \item{d} \linebreak
            \end{itemize}
        Text...
            \begin{itemize}
                \item{d}
                \item{e}
                \item{f}
                \item{g}
                \item{h}
                \item{i}
            \end{itemize}
         \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.pdf}

        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying and providing an MWE initially! All works perfectly now.

Comment: no problem, but f you liked answer you can vote (when you will can) or even accept it :-) . happy TeXing!